# Using a variable inside File.read?

Tags: ruby, json

Trying to read a text file of names and then use File.read.  But I get a no such file or directory error where indicated below:

```
# Read names.txt and create array - THIS PART WORKS
names = []
File.read('names.txt').each_line do |line|
    names << line.chop!
    end

# For first name in array, do this: - DOESN'T WORK = NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY #{names[0]}.json

json = File.read('#{names[0]}.json')

puts json
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using single-quoted string. It doesn't do interpolation. Use double quotes.

```
json = File.read("#{names[0]}.json")
```